# Jquery, CSS, SetTimeOut, GravityForms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code where in I need to change the color of the border and labels to this kind of color.

The code I have is ...

```
  <script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#input_28_1").attr("disabled", true);
   $('#input_27_1').val("");
   $('#input_27_1_2').val("");
});
```

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#gform_submit_button_27").click(function(e){

    var email1 = $('#input_27_1').val();
    var email2 = $('#input_27_1_2').val();

    //Oks na
    if (email1 == "" && email2 == "")
    {
      setTimeout(function()
      {
           $( ".gfield_description" ).clone().appendTo( "#clone-email-error" );
           $("#input_27_1_2").css("border", "1px solid #ec5665");
           $("label").css("color", "#333333");

      },1000);
     }

    //Oks na
    else if (email1 != "" && email2 == "")
    {
      setTimeout(function()
      {
           $( ".gfield_description" ).clone().appendTo( "#clone-email-error" );
           $("#input_27_1_2").css("border", "1px solid #ec5665");
           $("label").css("color", "#333333");

      },1000);
     }

    //Oks na
    else if (email1 == "" && email2 != "")
    {
      setTimeout(function()
      {
           $("label").css("color", "#333333");
           $("#input_27_1_2").css("border", "1px solid #E8E8E7");

      },1000);
     }
  });
```

});

I need to remove the setTimeout in order for the first text box and the second box to change color at the same time. But, whenever I try to remove the setTimeOut the .clone&.append & .css won't work.

Hope I get help. Thanks.

Comment: Is the DOM loaded at the time this code executes? Doesn’t sound like it.

Comment: on which particular event you are firing this function??

Comment: You set the time of your `setTimeout` functions to 1000 ms. This means the `function()` inside the `setTimeout()` will be executed after 1 second. Now if you remove the `setTimeout()` the won't be executed by an `event` anymore because there is nothing which executeds them (or you show us not enough of your code). So to execute your `function()`'s you need to call them by anything to remove the `setTimeout()`

Comment: Code updated. @DestinationN , if you're saying I need to put it to a function. Now how do I call if knowing that these are the only code I use?

Answer (score 0):

```
function test() {

    if (email1 == "" && email2 == "") {

        $(".gfield_description").clone().appendTo("#clone-email-error");
        $("#input_27_1_2").css("border", "1px solid #ec5665");
        $("label").css("color", "#333333");


    }

    //Oks na
    else if (email1 != "" && email2 == "") {

        $(".gfield_description").clone().appendTo("#clone-email-error");
        $("#input_27_1_2").css("border", "1px solid #ec5665");
        $("label").css("color", "#333333");

    }

    //Oks na
    else if (email1 == "" && email2 != "") {

        $("label").css("color", "#333333");
        $("#input_27_1_2").css("border", "1px solid #E8E8E7");


    }

}

var myVar = setTimeout(test, 1000);
```